# Install sf for r using gdal from postgresapp

Tags: r, gdal, r-sf, rgdal, postgis-installation

I am on MacOSX 11.4 Big Sur.

I have just installed on my computer https://postgresapp.com, which bundles PostgreSQL together with the needed libraries for PostGIS (proj, geos, and gdal).

I am able to use command line functions like ogr2ogr, gdalinfo etc. from my terminal, indicating that gdal is successfully installed.

I now want to install the "sf" package for R version 4.1.0. I am able to successfully install "sf", but the PostgreSQL driver is missing when I use the native installation

```
install.packages("sf")
```

According to the sf documentation and things I have read elsewhere on stack, this is a known issue for MacOSx, and the recommended workaround for this problem is to separately install gdal using homebrew or the kyngchaos binaries. However, I would like to use the gdal installation used by the postgresapp binary mentioned earlier so that there is only one installation on my computer..

According to the postgresapp installation documentation (https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html), the relevant paths are:

Binaries: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin

Headers: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/include

Libraries: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib

Therefore, when combined with the "sf" documentation my assumption is that the following should work.

```
install.packages("sf", configure.args = "--with-gdal-lib=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib/"
```

Although I receive no errors or warnings, this does not fix the problem for me as `sf::st_drivers()` still does not list the PostgreSQL driver as an option. Can someone please help me figure out what additional configuration arguments, if any, are needed to get sf to recognise the Postgres driver?

Comment: Did your issues resolve when they closed the issue ? https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1703

Comment: They did not close my issue, but closed a linked/related issue. As far as I know, they know what the fix is but have not yet implemented it.

Comment: I should also clarify that their intended fix would not answer my question, as they proposed an entirely different solution. So from a stack perspective, this question remains unanswered in terms of "how-to-do"

Comment: Thanks! I ran into a similar issue recently too.. My next step is trying out some docker containers.

Comment: @GISHuman let me know if it works. I suspect it won't because the issue is fundamental to how gdal compiles the drivers on install for Mac AMD

Comment: @GISHuman did the docker containers help you out?

Comment: I can't recall how I resolved this but I've been using conda (or mamba) to do all my gdal installs and in docker containers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to close this. The `sf` fixed the underlying gdal install scripts which is why it works now, nothing to do with conda or the containers.